# DD-WRT iptables rules not getting applied

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, linux-networking, openwrt

I am fairly new to networking, so bear with me if this turns out be a trivial question.

I have a DD-WRT router R1 (ip : 192.168.0.200) connected to another router R2 (ip : 192.168.0.1). R2 is connected to the ISP.

I want to block access to the internet for a particular IP (192.168.0.4) address connected to R1.

I want to acheive this using iptables.

I have the following rules.

```
iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       0    --  192.168.0.4          anywhere            
DROP       0    --  anywhere             192.168.0.4         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       0    --  192.168.0.4          anywhere            
DROP       0    --  anywhere             192.168.0.4         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       0    --  anywhere             192.168.0.4         
DROP       0    --  192.168.0.4          anywhere
```

And my routing table is as follows

```
route -n
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.200   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
```

Even after these rules i am still able to access the internet from the device with the IP 192.168.0.4

No packets hit the rules mentioned above. (0 packets when analysed using `iptables -L -vnx` )

Below is the traceroute from 192.168.0.4

```
$ traceroute stackexchange.com
traceroute to stackexchange.com (151.101.1.69), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.43.1 (192.168.43.1)  6.772 ms  6.800 ms  6.889 ms
 2  * * *
 3  10.40.24.129 (10.40.24.129)  48.875 ms  48.856 ms  48.848 ms
 4  125.20.84.161 (125.20.84.161)  48.420 ms  48.408 ms  48.401 ms
 5  182.79.187.6 (182.79.187.6)  158.759 ms 182.79.247.202 (182.79.247.202)  158.753 ms 182.79.187.6 (182.79.187.6)  162.258 ms
 6  * * *

$ ip route show
default via 192.168.43.1 dev wlp3s0 proto static metric 600 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.175 metric 600 


Is there something i am missing?
```

Comment: What's the default gateway for 192.168.0.4? Also please do a trace route and post the results.

Comment: Why do you think that 192.168.0.4 is connected to R1? It is probably connected to R2.

Comment: @Zalmy Updated the question with traceroute output

Comment: @MichaelHampton , No it is surely connected to R1. I notice the default gateway being set to R2 on my connection though. Is that a matter of concern?

Comment: Is the trace route from 0.4?

Comment: Yes, the traceroute is from 192.168.0.4

Comment: The default route seems like it's going to a different router. Is this computer also connected to wifi?

Comment: No it is connected only to R1 via Wifi

Answer (score 0):

Your client 192.168.0.4 is on the same subnet as R2; with R2 set as it's gateway even if physically wired into R1 the traffic will be switched at ethernet layer to R2 thus it doesn't pass through R1's routing/processing layer and iptables won't see it.

Either:

- Apply firewall rules on R2  (R1 is behaving only as a switch not a router)

or

- Separate R1's clients into a different subnet and VLAN on R1, using R1 as default gateway, which would force R1 to route traffic to R2, and then the iptables forwarding table rules would apply

or

- investigate ebtables/arptables (ethernet/switch firewalling - could have performance impact)